# How to redirect back to my iOS app after logging in on FitBit login page?

Tags: ios, swift, redirect, callback, fitbit

I am developing a very basic iOS app with Swift. Just to read the heart rate data. I am using SFSafariViewController. As known, I first need to register my app on dev.fitbit.com. The registration form requires a callback URL to be entered.

After logging in successfully, FitBit always redirects me back to that entered callback URL. What should I do/code/configure to be able to redirect user back to my iOS app after logging in successfully?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to add the `application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool` function to your AppDelegate and then create an url scheme for your application as an identifier. To create an url scheme go to your application target > Info > URL Types (at the bottom). Then just add the following in your AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Conctrol so that we´re coming from the right application
        if (url.scheme == "The url scheme that you created"){
            // Navigate to the viewController you want
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WebView") as! WebViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController!.present(controller, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
            })
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: After logging in successfully, FitBit redirects me back to that registered callback URL and sticks there. The `func appliation( __: )' function is not being called.  Please help me!

Comment: Fitbit Api does not currently have support for iOS deep linking. Try using the [following](http://deeplink.me) service to create an URL deeplink and then use the above code in my answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me what  [following](deeplink.me) service  means?

Comment: bro, after logging in successfully, it does not call the `func application( __: ).

Comment: @OConnor : did you set the call back URL (Your URL SCHEMA) in your OAuth call ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using below 3 steps in your application.

You are using "**fitbit**", so I am considering your are using **OAuth2.0** for login and get access-token.

**Step 1** : Set up you URL Schemes.

[image]

**Step 2** : In your **AppDelegate** class

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  if (url.host == "oauth-swift") {
    OAuthSwift.handle(url: url)
  }
  return true
}
```

In Above function what we did is, we check the URL comes to **handleOpenUrl** method, and check weather it is the right url call back is coming or not.

**Step 3** : Set the proper call back URL in you OAuth Handler.

```
oauthswift = OAuth2Swift(
    consumerKey:    "********",
    consumerSecret: "********",
    authorizeUrl:   "your authorisation url",
    responseType:   "token"
)
let handle = oauthswift.authorize(
    withCallbackURL: URL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/fitbit")!,
    scope: "your application scope", state:"state",
    success: { credential, response, parameters in
      print(credential.oauth_token)
    },
    failure: { error in
      print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
)
```

In above step, we set the call back url starting with "**oauth-swift:**", so it will be work as a host of your call back url.

> Image and Code Courtesy : I have tried to explain a solution of your
>   problem in easy words. And all information of this answers are
>   originally documented and explained on this URL :
>   https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift